# Misplaced alignment tab character & (for \cases)

Tags: equations, errors, cases

I'm using the \cases format to create the following equation:

[image]

by using:

```
\begin{equation}
\phi(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    
      <0, & \text{for}\  \Omega_1 \text{(Phase 1)} \\ 
      0, & \text{for}\  \Gamma \text{(Interface)} \\ 
      >0, & \text{for}\  \Omega_2 \text{(Phase 2)} 
    
    \end{cases}
 \label{eq.LS function}  
\end{equation}
```

Overleaf creates the equation but I receive the following error:
"Misplaced alignment tab character &"

I have not used the "&" anywhere in the text and it has been used only for equations.

Comment: Remove the blank lines after `\begin{cases}` and before `\end{cases}`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your reply. Still the same error.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{amsmath}` in you document preamble?

Comment: @egreg yes I do

Comment: Please, make a small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduce the error. Quite likely, in trying to make it, you'll find the source of the error. If not, we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following minimal working example and tested it successfully on Overleaf. As user `egreg` already implied, your code does not show a problem so it is difficult to guess what the problem is on your end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\phi(x,y)=\begin{cases}
      <0, & \text{for}\  \Omega_1 \text{ (Phase 1)} \\ 
      0, & \text{for}\  \Gamma \text{ (Interface)} \\ 
      >0, & \text{for}\  \Omega_2 \text{ (Phase 2)} 
    \end{cases}
\label{eq.LS function}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Basically, the problem was somewhere else! Some of journals name includes "&", and Overleaf couldn't understand it. Had to replace & with  \& in references.

Comment: @BroAli That's why it is important to provide a complete minimal code example and not just a fragment.